# there is not the hyper-individualism that characterises parts of the USA

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does "there is not the hyper-individualism that characterises parts of the USA" mean "there is not the hyper-individualism (**in Chinese people**) that characterises parts of the USA"?

> .
> “In China, you have a combination of a population that takes respiratory infections seriously and is willing to adopt non-pharmaceutical interventions, with a government that can put bigger constraints on individual freedoms than would be considered acceptable in most Western countries”, adds Poland. “Commitment to the greater good is engrained in the culture; **there is not the hyper-individualism that characterises parts of the USA**, and has driven most of the resistance to the countermeasures against the coronavirus.” Poland noted that the Chinese accept the notion that disease control is a matter of science. “China does not have the kind of raucous anti-vaccine, anti-science movement that is trying to derail the fight against COVID-19 in the USA”, he said.

> Source: [The Lancet](https://www.thelancet.com/journals/laninf/article/PIIS1473-3099(20)30800-8/fulltext)

Comment: I would say it means there is not the hyper-individualism in Chinese culture, rather than people, but otherwise, I agree with your interpretation.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty You shouldn't answer the question in the comments. Comments can be deleted or hidden away in chat without warning; answers should go in the answers.